# How do I properly use hook_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()?

Tags: 8, views

I have the following hook in mymodule.module.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $rows = $variables['rows'];

  if (in_array($view->id(),
      [
        'my_view',
      ]
    )
  )
    {
        foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {
          $custom_row_class = 'card-background-' . get_card_background();
          var_dump($custom_row_class);
          $variables['rows'][$id]['attributes']->addClass([$custom_row_class]);
        }

      var_dump($variables['rows'][0]['attributes']);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
/Users/me/Sites/mysite/web/modules/custom/mymodule/mymodule.module:55:string 'card-background-11' (length=18)

/Users/me/Sites/mysite/web/modules/custom/mymodule/mymodule.module:58:
object(Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute)[7400]
  protected 'storage' => 
    array (size=1)
      'class' => 
        object(Drupal\Core\Template\AttributeArray)[7223]
          protected 'value' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected 'name' => string 'class' (length=5)
```

Right after supposedly adding the class to the rows attributes, it isn't there, and not surprisingly isn't in the attributes value passed to views-view-unformatted.html.twig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code locally and the way you are adding the class did work for me. E.g.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$variables) {
  $rows = $variables['rows'];

  foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {
    $variables['rows'][$id]['attributes']->addClass(['test-123', 'test-abc']);
  }
}
```

... worked fine for me. I'd say your `var_dump()` is not giving you the full picture.

Try this instead:

```
var_dump($variables['rows'][0]['attributes']->__toString());
```

When I var dump with toString() - I see the class indicated in the output - hopefully you will too

```
/var/www/mysite/docroot/modules/custom/my_module/my_module.module:149:string ' class="card test-123 test-abc"' (length=31)
```