# How to retrieve view row attributes when in twig template

Tags: views, theming

I am using addClass() in hook_preprocess_views_view_unformatted (see my question regarding this at [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296724/using-hook-preprocess-views-view-unformatted-properly)), and the class is added to each row, but the next stop for the view results is views_view.html.twig, where dumping the rows data with

```
{{ dd(rows) }}
```

shows no sign of the attributes part of the row data, which contains the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *views-view.html.twig* template is at a higher level. To manipulate data at that level, you'll need to use [template_preprocess_views_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/8.2.x).

You used [template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted/8.2.x) which allows you to manipulate the data in *views-view-unformatted.html.twig*. This seems like the correct approach given your case.

Here are the contents of *views-view-unformatted.html.twig* from the views module in core.

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a view of unformatted rows.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - title: The title of this group of rows. May be empty.
 * - rows: A list of the view's row items.
 *   - attributes: The row's HTML attributes.
 *   - content: The row's content.
 * - view: The view object.
 * - default_row_class: A flag indicating whether default classes should be
 *   used on rows.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
{% if title %}
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
    ]
  %}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{- row.content -}}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

You can see that if you loop through the rows variable, each row has an attributes property - the classes you added in *template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()* will be part of it.